# Pulling data from multiple views using UNION ALL extremely slow

Tags: sql, union

so background is that I have 8 companies within an Accounting System. I have views for each of these 8 companies that have calculated columns and these reside on a different server. Then for certain reports I have to gather all the individual company data into a Division wide report. not the actual query but it looks something like:

```
select c.customer, c.address, c.custnumber, l.avgdayspay, l.datelastpayment
from AcompanyCustomer as c INNER JOIN
         AcompanyCustLedger as l on c.custnumber=l.custnumber

UNION ALL

select c.customer, c.address, c.custnumber, l.avgdayspay, l.datelastpayment
from BcompanyCustomer as c INNER JOIN
         BcompanyCustLedger as l on c.custnumber=l.custnumber
```

and so on. performance is horrible and takes over 45 minutes to run. individually the queries run anywhere from 4-45 seconds. is there a better way to write this? I researched and saw something about writing a function creating tables and inserting data from the views in tables but I couldn't get anything to work. not sure if someone has dealt with this and could maybe see something or know something I don't. thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: Put all the companies in a single table and use a `where` clause instead of `union all`.

Comment: While "uhg", for using multiple tables (manually 'table sharding' in SQL is most always a mistake) .. ensure that each of the individual queries is using appropriate indices. The time 'should' be: number_of_individual_queries * avg_time_of_each_individual_query (that is, the sum of time time for running all N queries separately), although some SQL implementations .. are less optimized. Also, the very act of using a UNION ALL could potentially change the query planner choices: and the query plan *should be the first place to look for performance information*.

Comment: Gordon.....thanks and that was kind of my idea behind a function to where I create the table, insert the data, and query from that. limited sql experience I could not get this to work. is there an example you could provide on how through a function or however else to do this? here is a short example of what I was trying......(I need to be able to execute this script to see if it's working but it always throws an error)....

Comment: sorry I hit the enter key. here is what I was trying with erro                                                                                                              CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DivisionAging()
RETURNS @Aledger TABLE(
[Customer No_] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[TotalARBalance] [float] NOT NULL,
[LastYearSales] [float] NOT NULL
)

AS
BEGIN
INSERT @Aledger(
[Customer No_],
[TotalARBalance],
[LastYearSales]
)
SELECT *
FROM dbo.FCTN_Acustomer('6/7/2017') 
RETURN
END